# jQuery wrap and place a class using array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

i would like to wrap the h3 tag and the div under to a div with a class of the follow array how can i achieve this with jQuery?

**heres my current code:**

```
$sections = array('section1','section2','section3');


<h3>Section Title 1</h3>
<div class="options_1">
    <p>Some Options</p>
</div>

<h3>Section Title 2</h3>
<div class="options_2">
    <p>Some Options</p>
</div>

<h3>Section Title 3</h3>
<div class="options_3">
    <p>Some Options</p>
</div>
```

**and this what i want to accomplish**

```
$sections = array('section1','section2','section3');

<div class="section1">
    <h3>Section Title 1</h3>
    <div class="options_1">
        <p>Some Options</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="section2">
    <h3>Section Title 2</h3>
    <div class="options_2">
        <p>Some Options</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="section3">
    <h3>Section Title 3</h3>
    <div class="options_3">
        <p>Some Options</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $sections = ['section1', 'section2', 'section3'];

$("h3").each(function(idx){
    var next = $(this).next();
    var c = $sections[idx];
    $(this).wrap('<div class="'+c+'" />').parent().append(next);
});
```

Comment: this one works but i want to use the classname with the array that i specify. using the text of the h3 for class wont work assuming you i have <h3>Section Title 1</h3>;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you want the class name of the new div to be the text of the `<h3>` tag, you can do it like this:

```
$("h3").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    var section = $('<div class="' + text + '"></div>');
    section.insertBefore(this);
    var next = $(this).next();
    section.append(this).append(next);
});
```

This gets the text of each `<h3>`, creates a new div with that as a class name, inserts it before the `<h3>` tag, then inserts the `<h3>` and the following sibling object as children of the new div.

Comment: this doesn't include the div under the h3 tag.